# Jenkins pipeline docker agent, Start docker conatiner from Dockerfile with previliged mode

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my jenkins pipeline, the pipeline code and Dockerfile is available at gitlab

```
pipeline {
 agent { dockerfile true }
  stages {
   stage('Test') {
    steps {
     sh '''
      java -version
      chmod 777 /data
     '''
    }
   }
  }
}
```

From the Dockerfile the image gets created and docker container gets started but missing some privilages.
can not even create a directory
Need to start the docker container with privilages so that I can perform this chmod, mkdir, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`agent { dockerfile ..` supports arguments. See [docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#dockerfile)

```
agent {
    // Equivalent to "docker build -f Dockerfile.build
    dockerfile {
        filename 'Dockerfile.build'
        args '--privileged'
    }
}
```